# PySpark: How to extract variables from a struct nested in a struct inside an array?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following is a toy example that is a subset of my actual data's schema. I abbreviated it for brevity.

I am looking to build a PySpark dataframe that contains 3 fields: `ID`, `Type` and `TIMESTAMP` that I would then save as a Hive Table. I am struggling with the PySpark code to extract the relevant columns.

```
 |-- Records: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- FileID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- SrcFields: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- TIMESTAMP: string (nullable = true)
```

Thus far, I imagine my solution should look something like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

df.withColumn("values", explode("values")).select(
  "*", col("values")["name"].alias("name"), col("values")["id"].alias("id")
)
```

However, the solution above doesn't account for the extra nesting of my use-case and I'm unable to figure out the additional syntax required.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PySpark you can access subfields of a struct using dot notation. So something like this should work:

1. Explode the array
2. Use the dot notation to get the subfields of struct

```
(
  df.withColumn("values", explode("Records"))
  .select(
    col("values.SrcFields.ID").alias("id"), 
    col("values.SrcFields.Type").alias("type"), 
    col("values.SrcFields.TIMESTAMP").alias("timestamp")
  )
)
```

Comment: `"cannot resolve 'explode(`values`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct`

Comment: @user2205916 Sorry, in the explode function should be of course the array column. I edited the answer.

Comment: How to access key/value in a MapType column with dot?